# Node js Formiadable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, formidable

I am new to node.js and learning it from various sources such as bootcamps, websites, etc. I want to upload a file using formidable module in node.js and express.js framework. Everytime I run this code i can not see the console.logs in the termianal.After the submit button my page starts to load and nothing happens. What i did wrong?

**HTML file**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<form  action="/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type = "file" multiple/>
   <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
const express  = require("express")
const fm  = require("formidable")
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app  = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
    .use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.get("/", (req, res)=>{

    res.sendFile( __dirname + "/file.html")
})
app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
    const form = new fm.IncomingForm()
    form.parse(req, (err, fileds, files)=>{
        console.log(files, "files")
    })
    form.on("fileBegin", (name, file)=>{
        console.log("name, file")
    })
    form.on("file", (name, file)=>{
        console.log(file, name)
    })

})

app.listen( 3000, ()=>{
    console.log("port is running")
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You have a typo in `form.parse` : `(err, fileds, files)` should be `(err,fields,files)`
2. Also, in HTML, you are missing the `name` attribute; try with something like:
   `<input type = "file" name = "myfiles" multiple/>`
3. Your express response never happens, and the client waits forever. Finalize  a response for the client, maybe just:

```js
form.on("file", (name,file)=>{
console.log(file, name)
res.send('received')
})
```